# Can I rename pyodbc egg to odbc egg on ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyodbc

For whatever reason from dark history, we have been running our system using pyodbc on windows for a long time now, but it is called odbc.

Now trying to port to Linux, I have installed pyodbc, but now my long running code cannot "import odbc", though "import pyodbc" works fine.

One solution is to "if sys.plateform.find('linux')" and do a "import pyodbc as odbc" or "import pyodbc" depending, but that seems hacky.

Is there a way to just rename the egg?

I tried naively just renaming the two files and the "import odbc" finds those files . . . but then seems to be confused because of internal naming:

```
  File "/local/mnt/workspace/aswp401/source/qcom/qct/modem/arch/sandbox/fmerrow/hub/py/utils/dbutils.py", line 1, in 
    import odbc
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initodbc)
```

The problem of course being that the function is named initpyodbc, not initodbc.

Is there an offcial way to do such a rename?  Or is sys.platform my best option?

Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to handle this is:

```
try:
    import pyodbc
except ImportError:
    import odbc as pyodbc
```

Unless there's some compelling reason to do otherwise, don't try to guess which one will be installed, just try them out. This is a case of [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)—but in addition to the usual advantages, there's the fact that it will continue to work even if your guesses later become invalid (e.g., because you set up an OpenBSD machine, upgrade the package on your Windows machine, …).

It's generally better to try the official current name of the module first, then try older/variant/etc. names as a fallback.

It's also generally better to *use* the official current name throughout your code… but if you've already got a lot of code that does `odbc.this` and `odbc.that`, and you don't trust a simple search-and-replace or other refactoring tools at your disposal, you can `import pyodbc as odbc` instead.

---

Just renaming the egg may or may not work (it looks like it won't in your case), but it's a bad idea even if it does.

At the very least, it will confuse your package manager (whether that's `apt`, `easy_install`, `pip`, or something else). For example, it may not be able to upgrade or uninstall the package, install other packages that depend on it, etc.

Worst of all, it may "mostly" work, but then fail because, e.g., some code buried in a C extension module in the middle of the package relies on a fully qualified module name, and that code only gets called in some rare edge case of your app.